# What are these small black specs inside my peppers?

Tags: food-safety, vegetables, kitchen-safety, seeds, pepper

Inside my pepper (pic) are these small black/brown specs. What are they? Are they safe to eat?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are infertile seeds. If you notice, they are on the ribs of the pepper, where the seeds develop. Because they are infertile, they have not developed beyond the very early stages of development.

Comment: yes, that's what I was thinking. So the pepper and these infertile seeds are safe to eat?

Comment: Yes, peper seeds, whether fully grown or infantile can be eaten. But if is often also easy to take the seeds out as they are on the ribs.